# Does Wyrdward effect applies for Ancients attacks?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

[Wyrdward](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wyrdward) ring:

> Lightning damage has a 13–17% chance to Stun for 1.5 seconds.

If a barb uses [call of the ancients](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/call-of-the-ancients) with the 'Together as One' rune, does the ring proc?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it.

Equipped the ring, summoned the ancients, removed my weapons for low damage and watched them hit mobs at T1 for a few minutes, no stuns.

Then tried hitting them myself and verified that the proc works.

So in my conclusion Wyrdward does not proc on CotA with the "Together as One" rune.